# Reliably getting the calling function's file path

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a function `foo()`. When invoked, I want that function to reliably determine the file path of the module (or the calling function) that invoked it. The issue is that various functions in the `inspect` module only return relative paths (relative to the working directory at the time of import, I assume). However, my code switches working directories multiple times and I don't know the working directory in question.

```
import inspect
import os

def foo():
    frame = inspect.stack()[0]
    print(frame.filename)
    print(os.path.abspath(frame.filename))

foo()

os.chdir("/")
print("New CWD:", os.getcwd())

foo()
```

Output:

```
$ cd ~
$ python3 foo.py
foo.py
/home/user/foo.py
New CWD: /
foo.py
/foo.py
```

Through auto-completion in my IDE I discovered that there's an undocumented function `inspect.getabsfile()`. Unfortunately, that doesn't work reliably, either:

```
import inspect

def foo():
    print("Hello")

print(inspect.getabsfile(foo))

os.chdir("/")
print("New CWD:", os.getcwd())

print(inspect.getabsfile(foo))
```

Output:

```
$ cd ~
$ python3 foo.py
/home/user/foo.py
New CWD: /
/foo.py
```

If I understand [this bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue12317) correctly, `__file__` and `code.co_filename` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members)) were (are?) going to become absolute paths at some point that hasn't happened (yet). What can I do to solve this issue in the meantime?

*Update:* Turns out the main issue with the above two example scripts is that they access objects / stack frames originating in the main module. As soon as one imports an object from a different module or considers the stack frame of a function living in another module, it works. In a similar way, in other modules than `__main__`, `__file__` indeed gives absolute path. (See also [this issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue18416) in the Python bug tracker.) I'm at a loss as to why the main module is being treated differently, though.

Answer (score 2):

With use of `closure` technique, you can store script path in *import time*, thus just checking if a function is from `__main__` is enough to get path of all 3 following cases:

- `from ~ import ~`
- `import ~`
- object defined in main script

Following example demonstrates all 3:

```
from sys import modules
from os.path import abspath
from os import getcwd, chdir

from Module import a
import timeit


def closure():
    original_working_dir = abspath(__file__)  # store absolute path for linux

    def _get_path(obj):
        nonlocal original_working_dir

        try:
            return abspath(obj.__file__)

        except AttributeError:  # it's probably not a module
            if obj.__module__ == '__main__':  # check if module is same as local:
                return abspath(original_working_dir)

            return abspath(modules[obj.__module__].__file__)
    return _get_path


get_path = closure()


def test_func():
    pass


def test_output():
    print(f"\nworking directory: {getcwd()}")
    print(f"import from: {get_path(a)}")
    print(f"simple import: {get_path(timeit)}")
    print(f"local function: {get_path(test_func)}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_output()
    chdir('/')
    test_output()
```

output for windows:

```
working directory: Z:\github\StackOverFlow\63865883
import from: Z:\github\StackOverFlow\63865883\Module.py
simple import: C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\timeit.py
local function: Z:\github\StackOverFlow\63865883\63865883.py

working directory: Z:\
import from: Z:\github\StackOverFlow\63865883\Module.py
simple import: C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\timeit.py
local function: Z:\github\StackOverFlow\63865883\63865883.py
```

Ubuntu:

```
working directory: /mnt/z/github/StackOverFlow/63865883
import from: /mnt/z/github/StackOverFlow/63865883/Module.py
simple import: /usr/lib/python3.8/timeit.py
/mnt/z/github/StackOverFlow/63865883/63865883.py
local function: /mnt/z/github/StackOverFlow/63865883/63865883.py

working directory: /
import from: /mnt/z/github/StackOverFlow/63865883/Module.py
simple import: /usr/lib/python3.8/timeit.py
/mnt/z/github/StackOverFlow/63865883/63865883.py
local function: /mnt/z/github/StackOverFlow/63865883/63865883.py
```

---

Main reason why your code worked correctly time-to-time is because `__file__` attribute of main script depends on whether you ran python script with relative path or absolute path.

Seems like `__file__` for main script stores file parameter given to python interpreter from terminal.

For example, when running this file:

```py
print(__file__)
```

when called relatively via `python3 scratch.py`:

```
scratch.py
```

You get absolute path for it.

with absolute path `python3 /mnt/c/~~/scratches/scratch.py`:

```
/mnt/c/Users/--/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharm2020.2/scratches/scratch.py
```

You get full path for `__file__`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem: `print(get_path(foo)); os.chdir("/"); print(get_path(foo))` will still give the wrong path after changing the working directory.

Comment: Good catch, yes, I did try it with a function that was inside the main script (like in my code above). I just tried it with some object I imported from somewhere else and it worked! In fact, calling `inspect.getabsfile()` on that object worked, too! Moreover, it seems `frame.filename` *also* gives the correct result for all frames which do not originate in the main script. I'm at a loss why the main script causes trouble, though…

Comment: Side note regarding your answer: The NamedTuple `inspect.stack()[1]` doesn't contain the calling function as an object but only its name, so I'm not sure how one would go about finding the module of the calling function (in order to access its `__file__` property). Good thing that `frame.filename` seems to work now (at least outside the main module), so at least I've got a workaround!

Comment: Finally figured out issue and fixed it, check out added comment on bottom of post!

Comment: I see you've changed your post rather significantly since yesterday. Maybe it would be worth pointing out in the very beginning of your answer that you're now addressing the only remaining part of my question, namely that about objects originating in the main module, and that you solve this issue by storing the path to the main module before `chdir()` is called for the first time. I'll happily mark your answer as correct but we should at least make it intelligible for future visitors.

Comment: Also, please note that your answer is actually not addressing the precise question I asked: I still don't see how I would obtain the calling function (as an object, not a string!) from `inspect.stack()`. But this would certainly be required to apply your solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I want my function `foo()` to find out who the caller is and in what file that calling function lives. Whether or not that requires the module `inspect` I don't know (though it's likely). What would need monkey-patching?

Comment: Cleared up my comments for a fresh start: Can you give me more detail about how(arguments), when ```inspect.stack``` will be called, and precisely what function you want to get from it?

Comment: If these unknown factors aren't a problem for non-main modules, how about simply creating new *main* script and importing original *main* script?

Comment: Sure, in that case I would simply use `inspect.stack()[1].filename` to get the caller's absolute file path and be done with it. Actually, now that I'm thinking about it, I could even do without a new main script and instead employ a similar trick to yours to handle the case where the caller is the main module: Namely, I could simply test whether `inspect.stack()[1].filename` is an absolute path. If it is not, then it must be the main module and I can simply prepend the original working directory to get the full path.

Comment: Good to hear that, I'll be expecting your solution - sounds interesting